# Not able to access special characters i.e. @,( etc

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications

How do I access special characters on the keyboard when writing emails? I push the Shift key and the 2 to receive the @ but it continues to give me a 2 what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong with your keyboard, but I will try to show you a way to find out which characters you can enter with it
(I'll have to check if this works on newer systems).
First, open the System Preferences.

[image: OS X System Preferences - Keyboard]

Click the `Keyboard` icon to get

[image: Keyboard Preferences]
Make sure that the box to the left of `Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar` is checked. If it is, then you should find this symbol
[image: Keyboard Viewer Icon in Menu Bar]
in the menu bar. Click on it and choose `Show Keyboard Layout` in the dopdown menu, which gives you this

[image: Keyboard Viewer]

and even better, when you press modifier keys, the Keyboard Viewer will show the characters you would get if you pressed a key.