# How to write (not so) special characters on non US keyboards

Tags: keyboard

I'm working in a programming lab where a lot of students are using the excellent MacBook Air hardware. Problems arise when they use virtualization to start let's say an Ubuntu machine to start their first hello world in c++. (a unix/linux like environment is required by the instructions and while osx would in principle be usable, it is in practice a more complex solution)

The keyboards usually comes with a Swedish keyboard layout. The characters Å (sits to the right of P) and Ö and Ä (sits to the right of L.) bumps off a lot of the useful programming stuff it seems.

Lets look at

```
#include<iostream>
```

Problems start with #, include is readily typed on the keyboard. The next problem is <, then of course >.

Then `int main()` is manageable, but that curly thingy for the statement block was Option and 7?

of course

```
std::cout << "Hello Think different\n";
```

Should be straightforward but I had to do some serious keyboard mashing to find backslash under the plus sign.

Is there a cheat sheet for the keyboard combinations for the regular programming symbols not visible on the keyboard.

Examples:

```
<>[]{}\#
```

I expect there to be more symbols I missed.

I noticed this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/148336/439180 quite not duplicate. Because they are in a virtual machine the near duplicate is quite impractical.

What is the easiest way to (remember how to ) type these characters?

The level of proficiency of OsX/computer use fluctuates wildly. The simpler the better.

Comment: Sorry what is the isseue #<> are shown on the keyboard you just need shift?

Comment: We need more information - all these are easily typed and visible on a mac keyboard unless your shift key is broken except [] which doesd not need shift. What keyboard do you have

Comment: What country keyboard was used - if American or British most of these are easy

Comment: @mmmmmm  Yes, I was curiously unable to deduce that should have been part of the question. It is now included.  Also, nice find about my defect!

Comment: Have you tried the [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/mac)? Unfortunately, no keyboard shortcut exists to launch it AFAIK. [This web page](https://www.webnots.com/how-to-use-keyboard-viewer-to-find-shortcuts-in-mac/), I think, has a better user guide than Apple's for the Keyboard Viewer.

Comment: MacBook with Swedish layout I get: `⌥` + `7` as `{ `; `⌥` + `0` as `}` ; `⌥` + `8` as `[` ; `⌥` + `9` as `]`, `shift` + `3` as `#` and `⌥` + `+` as  \ . For `<` and `>` there is dedicated key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are key mappings for Option and Option Shift for the Swedish Pro Input Source, in case these are helpful:

[image: Swedish Pro Option Level]

[image: Swedish Pro Option Shift Level]